# validation rule should not fire for the Manager of the Opportunity Owner

Tags: apex, visualforce, validation-rule

The validation rule should not fire for the Manager of the Opportunity Owner.

```
Probability > 0.90
```

&&  RecordTypeId = "012qui000002se456"
&&  ISPICKVAL(Multi_Quarter_Delivery__c,"")

&& NOT( $User.IntegrationUser__c )

```
*&& NOT($User.Id = Owner.Id)*   // please suggest me on this.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to add one more condition(With && condition).

```
Owner.Manager.Id  <>  $User.Id
```

It says if the manager of the owner of opportunity is not equal to the id of the user then apply validation rule.

Comment: you mean &&Not( $User.Manager.Id = $user.Id)

Comment: No, you want to check for the opportunity owner so you have to apply this: `&&Not( Owner.Manager.Id = $user.Id)` .I removed my previous comment.

Comment: ISPICKVAL( Account.Business_Unit__c ,"VIS")&&
Probability > 0.59&&
RecordTypeId = "012w00000002PE5"&&
ISPICKVAL(Multi_Quarter_Delivery__c,"")

&& NOT( $User.IntegrationUser__c )

&& NOT( $User.IntegrationUser__c  )

&& NOT($User.Id = Owner.Id) && Not( Owner.Manager.Id = $user.Id) So finally it will be like this.

Comment: yes this is exactly what i want to say.

Comment: @CodeDictator Please mark answer correct if it solved your issue.